# pass function as parameter with and withou ampersand c

Tags: c, function, parameters

I want to pass a function as parameter, but I am confused if I should pass it with ampersand or not. The following snippet works in both ways. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int print(int pas){
return pas;
}


int func_print(int (*k)(int)){
(*k)(555);
}

int main(){



printf("%d",func_print(print));
printf("%d",func_print(&print));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is implicitly converted to a pointer to a function.

Answer (score 1):

Function names are special.

When used without calling the function, it automatically is translated to a pointer to the function.  So `&print`, `print`, `*print`, `**print`, `***print`, etc. all evaluate to the same expression of type `int (*)(int)`.

Comment: In fact, a function identifier is converted to a pointer to the function *wherever* it appears in a valid expression, except as the operand of the address-of, `sizeof`, or `_Alignof` operators (C11 6.3.2.1/4).  In particular, this is the only type family allowed for the operand of a function call expression: "The expression that denotes the called function shall have type pointer to function [...]" (C11 6.5.2.2/1).  This is closely analogous to arrays decaying to pointers.